# Python Pillow not working on raspbian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, python-imaging-library, easy-install

I installed Pillow 3.3.0 using easy_install (pip install results in the same behavior). After succesfull installation I get an "illegal instruction" error when I import the Image class.

The output of the installation:

```
root@rasp01:/data/server# easy_install Pillow
Searching for Pillow
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Pillow/
Best match: Pillow 3.3.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/e0/27/f61098a12f14690689924de93ffdd101463083a80bf8ff3e0c218addf05b/Pillow-3.3.0.tar.gz#md5=b5a15b03bf402fe254636c015fcf04da
Processing Pillow-3.3.0.tar.gz
Running Pillow-3.3.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-c1OEYc/Pillow-3.3.0/egg-dist-tmp-iwARkP
Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile:1 processes
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 3.3.0
platform     linux2 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
             [GCC 4.6.3]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- JPEG support available
*** OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support not available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT support not available
*** LIBTIFF support not available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS2 support not available
*** WEBP support not available
*** WEBPMUX support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library and headers.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.

Adding Pillow 3.3.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pilfont.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing thresholder.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing gifmaker.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing viewer.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing createfontdatachunk.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing enhancer.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilconvert.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilfile.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing player.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing explode.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pildriver.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing painter.py script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pilprint.py script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pillow-3.3.0-py2.7-linux-armv6l.egg
Processing dependencies for Pillow
Finished processing dependencies for Pillow
```

And the output of the error:

```
root@rasp01:/data/server# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
Illegal instruction
root@rasp01:/data/server#
```

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
    from PIL import *
```

and just import everything from the library instead

or if that doesn't work try

```
    import PIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi uses ARM, PILLOW that is installed is not compatible, hence the instruction is illegal.

Try installing PILLOW with `sudo apt-get` command

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. Eventually I installed PIL using:

```
    sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

This installed PIL in the right architecture an is working.